Not Able to Sync Gradle for libs in Android
I am trying to setup existing Android Project .
But , I am getting below error .
Could not HEAD 'https://repo.spring.io/plugins-snapshot/com/jfrog/bintray/gradle/gradle-bintray-plugin/1.6/gradle-bintray-plugin-1.6.pom'. Received status code 401 from server: 
My Project level build.gradle is

buildscript {
repositories {
mavenCentral()
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2' }
google()
maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/plugins-snapshot'}
}

dependencies {
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.2'
classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.6'
classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.1'
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.21"
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:1.6.10"
classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.4.1'
}

Error
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.6.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.6.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.spring.io/plugins-snapshot/com/jfrog/bintray/gradle/gradle-bintray-plugin/1.6/gradle-bintray-plugin-1.6.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://repo.spring.io/plugins-snapshot/com/jfrog/bintray/gradle/gradle-bintray-plugin/1.6/gradle-bintray-plugin-1.6.pom'. Received status code 401 from server: 


Edit :
When I click on link "https://repo.spring.io/plugins-snapshot/com/jfrog/bintray/gradle/gradle-bintray-plugin/1.6/gradle-bintray-plugin-1.6.pom" it asks for authentication which is from jfrog .
But other users from my team are able to run the project without any issue .
Is it to do with jcenter migration ?
I checked in https://repo.spring.io/ without authentication .. below is screenshot . Is the jfrog not there now or requires authentication .
Spring Repo Image
Need a solution How to solve the gradle sync . This is first setup to be done .

Please read this blog post from 2022 about spring.io Maven repo https://spring.io/blog/2022/12/14/notice-of-permissions-changes-to-repo-spring-io-january-2023

Can I get explanation @Robert. since some of my teammates are able to run projects without issues

Some projects or this project? It just depends which dependencies you try to load. Most dependencies are mosten on maven central or Google repo. spring.io is pretty uncommon. You can search the dependencies on https://mvnrepository.com/ and it will display in which repositories the dependency is available.

This project only @Robert

Is it due to "https://repo.spring.io/ui/native/plugins-snapshot" , Should I use authentication ? As other users are able to do it without authentication

Most likely they have the files still cached locally on their system and thus don't need to redownload them.

Any solution you suggest .. I tried from one post https://jfrog.com/blog/jcenter-sunset/ ... but I dont see they have artifact bintray-plugin:1.6. @Robert

Just in case it would help, I found this stackoverflow post.

but regarding to the error code 401, that is strange because it shows you are not authorised, but not sure how it would happen. Oh, I just checked the link, it is actually normal you get 401, you need username and password.
